# background.js is being triggered every refresh

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

It seems as if my background.js is triggered every refresh [planted an alert, and i see it every refresh, also my context menu is duplicating its inner self].

this is my manifest file:

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "test",
"description": "test",
"version": "1.0",
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus", 
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab*"
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "raj_robot.png",
    "default_title" : "MemoMi"
},
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab" : "mypage.html"
},
"background": {
    "scripts" : ["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js" : ["selection.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
}
],
```

And this is my background script:

```
function handle_click() {
    alert("hi there!");
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({

    title: "menu title", 
    contexts:["selection"], 
    onclick: handle_click

});
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!
Gura

Comment: What's in your background script?  Also, your content script, since (IIRC) that's the only one that should be refreshing.

Comment: Added to the question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it. I was actually implicitly triggering background.js by using methods in the content scripts, that should have been in the background.js. Just comment out your code and and see if it improves.